# Integrating and Automating Build Process for iOS, Android and Blackberry

Tags: android, ios, blackberry, build, continuous-integration

Which tools can be used to automate the build process for a native mobile app being developed targeting iOS (Objective C), Android (Java SDK for Android), Blackberry (Java SDK for BB)?

1. Please share your thoughts on Versioning System, Build Script Tool, Integration.
2. Is it possible to setup a single automated build process for all platforms?
3. What about automated deployment on devices. Can this be achieved?
4. Automating execution of Unit Tests
5. Please share links to any case studies, documents which may be of relevance.

Thanks in advance.